# made react.js, Chrome extension loses focus, how to force the pop-up force redering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

It's as it is.
I am not good at English.

I know that the Chrome extension closes when you click on the current window(not popup, in your current Tab window).

But sometimes when i open the extension again after closing the pop-up window,
the previous state is maintained(Ex... folder open or already checked).

But if it doesn't keep going, but it changes state(meaning setState in react), pop-ups become renderings from the beginning.

So there are times when I'm surprised when I'm using it.

I have also touched runtime and now I import the chrome API from another folder and use it. So even if I try to use runtime, I don't know what part of the react to run and let it go.

I've seen the use of blur, but I don't know how to apply it to react.

I beg you. 
I've been thinking about it a lot and trying, but I don't know how.

Comment: Hello Lee, I speak normally french but I understand your english :-) But ... In your first sentence what is "the current window" ? Can you give more information about when this problem occurs: "There are times when" is not enough. I think that there is a mistake to title: what is "reder", is it "rendering" ?

Comment: @schlebe Thank schlebe there are times is my mistake..ㅠㅠ  I'll fix my word

Comment: It's not clear what exactly happens so a screencast would be helpful. The standard extension popup page is completely destroyed when closed so there's absolutely no way it can maintain its previous state. So far this sounds like a bug either in Chrome or in your code. I doubt this question is answerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm. thanks wox. It's so hard to explain through picture. I'll take a video and upload it. I sympathize with you saying that if the pop-up goes out, everything will be shut down. But if I have a state and a state change, then rendering will occur.